# How do I execute a ruby script with a method but no class?

Tags: ruby

I have:

```
def is_valid_cool_string(str)
  ...
end
```

And I want to write something like

```
is_valid_cool_string("Foobar")
```

at the bottom of the file to do this. Is there like a main method or something like that?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you try running it? If so, what errors did you get? If not, go run it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need anything to make this work. :)

Don't forget to print the result if the method returns something.

```
puts is_valid_cool_string("Foobar")
```

or something like

```
puts "Is valid: #{is_valid_cool_string("Foobar").inspect}"
```